# ReferenceError: [...] is not defined

Tags: javascript, file, class, canvas, referenceerror

I am trying to use a JS function which is in an another JS file and I have this error :

> ReferenceError: Lanceur is not defined

Lanceur is my object which is defined in my second file.
I have a constructor :

```
public class Lanceur { 
  constructor(angleAiguille) {
    this.angleAiguille = angleAiguille;
  } // And functions .....
```

I have this line in my first file : `lanceur = new Lanceur(0);`

And I call my files in a HTML files with `<script src="js/canvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`, for example.

Comment: You need to load the class before making an instance from it. So if the class is in the second file and the new Lanceur() call in the first, you need to swap the files around.

Comment: Are you compiling this with something? Your use of `public` confuses me, are you sure you don't mean `class Lanceur { }`?

Comment: Thank you Shilly and James. Now, how I call my functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the class before you can create an instance of it. You also don't need the keyword `public` as browsers don't support it currently *(Unless you're compiling this through Babel or something similar, but that wasn't obvious from your post)*.

In your first file include the code that makes up the class, I've added a method as an example.

```
class Lanceur { 
  constructor(angleAiguille) {
    this.angleAiguille = angleAiguille;
  }

  someMethod() { 
   console.log('Firing') 
  }
}
```

You can then create an instance of it like so in your second file and call its methods.

```
const instance = new Lanceur;


// Calling a method...
instance.someMethod();
```

You can learn more about JavaScript class constructors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).