# Getting msg="ReferenceError: tv4 is not defined for k6 implementation in github actions

Tags: postman, github-actions, load-testing, k6

I am trying to perform a load test using k6 by converting Postman collection JSON files into k6 script files through GitHub Actions. However, during execution, But on execution I see the error in GitHub actions as

```
`time="2023-12-21T12:36:12Z" level=error msg="ReferenceError: tv4 is not defined\n\tat file:///github/workspace/k6-script.js:86:21(1)\n\tat test (file:///github/workspace/libs/shim/core.js:504:6(15))\n\tat post (file:///github/workspace/k6-script.js:85:14(61))\n\tat executePostrequest (file:///github/workspace/libs/shim/core.js:1253:11(22))\n\tat executeRequest (file:///github/workspace/libs/shim/core.js:1034:25(108))\n\tat file:///github/workspace/libs/shim/core.js:314:30(27)\n\tat file:///github/workspace/k6-script.js:38:19(39)\n" executor=constant-vus scenario=default source=stacktrace`
```

for schema validation using tv4 .
Example:

```
pm.test("Schema validation", function(){
    var result = tv4.validateResult(pm.response.json(),schema);
    if(!result.valid){
        console.log(result)
    }
    pm.expect(result.valid).to.be.true;
})
```

How can i solve this issue?

How can we verify the json schema through tv4 in k6?

Comment: What is `tv4`? Where do you assign a value to this identifier?

Comment: Tv4 is json schema validator, available in postman for test automation

Comment: But k6 isn't postman. You can't assume functionality of postman to be available within k6. You can try installing and importing tv4 in your k6 script, but as I understand, the project is no longer maintained, according to its GitHub page.

Comment: This is how er are converting the postman json to the k6 js file and running in github actions 

postman-to-k6 ${{ github.workspace }}/postman/collections/catalog.json -o catalog.js 

- uses: grafana/k6-action@v0.2.0 with: filename: catalog.js flags: --vus 50 --duration 10s

Comment: postman-to-k6 is no longer maintained: https://github.com/grafana/postman-to-k6, development has stopped. k6 isn't postman. If you're code is using libraries, you have to make sure the library is installed and properly imported.

Comment: [What is a ReferenceError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415166/referenceerror-is-not-defined) and [how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934818/what-is-a-referenceerror-and-how-to-fix-it)